# Link to Anchor on the same page minus some pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I integrated smooth scrolling to an anchor to my page. It works great with the code:

```
$(function() {
      $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Now when i click a link, it scrolls to that position. But since i got a fixed menubar on the top (height: 100px), it overlaps the content a bit. 
Can i fix this somehow? like say in the code: scroll to that anchor minus 100px...
i thought it might work with

```
scrollTop: target.offset(-100).top
```

is that right?

Comment: `scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100` ?

Comment: Oh thanks! I tried this but forgot the space between the - and the 100... Stupid me >.< Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I've made it an answer here. Maybe mark it as solution. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) is a function to just give you an elements offset. This is not mean to change the offset itself. Just substract the 100px afterwards.

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top - 100
```